# Change Page Content as per WordPress Theme Selection

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I want to change page content as per theme selection of WordPress
Is there any way to do it ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sorry i do not understand your question. Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: I need to change home page content automatically when i am change theme

Comment: The contend in WP is normaly seperated from the theme (since theme is only the styling and so on).
You could add hardcoded content to the theme (which is not way to go) or define different placeholder in the themes which might be a solution to somehow switch content by defining different content for the placeholders